# Only print when the button is pressed and not being pressed anymore

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, button

I have an Arduino and a [microswitch](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/microswitches/1594590/) that I want to use to know when the switch is initially being pressed (get "OnsetTime" on Serial) and when the switch is not being pressed anymore (get "OffsetTime" on Serial).

Imagine a bird sitting on the switch. I want to get an output "OnsetTime" when the bird first sits on the switch and an output "OffsetTime" when the bird flies away from the switch.

Right now, I have an output that constantly prints out "OnsetTime" when the switch is pressed. 
I would appreciate it if anybody can help me figure out how can I implement the below code to get the outputs only when the switch is initially pressed and not being pressed anymore.

```
void setup() {
  pinMode(7, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {  
  if (digitalRead(7) == HIGH) {
    Serial.println("OnsetTime");
    }
}
    //Serial.println("GetOffsetTime");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be simple, you can use [this library](https://www.arduinolibraries.info/libraries/ez-button). The code will be

```
#include <ezButton.h>

ezButton button(7);  // create Button object that attach to pin 7;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  button.setDebounceTime(100); // set debounce time to 100 milliseconds
}

void loop() {
  button.loop(); // MUST call the loop() function first

  if(button.isPressed())
    Serial.println("OnsetTime");

  if(button.isReleased())
    Serial.println("GetOffsetTime");
}
```

If you want to understand in depth, You can see the code and instruction in [this tutorial](https://arduinogetstarted.com/tutorials/arduino-button#content_modifying_arduino_code)

Comment: Hi. This gives me the error: 'class Button' has no member named 'setDebounceTime'

Comment: did you install ezButton library ? if not, follow [this instruction](https://arduinogetstarted.com/tutorials/arduino-button-library) to install libraray

Comment: Yes, I did. This is an unusual case so I'm a bit confused. Did you try it and does it work?

Comment: Yes, I tried, it works. I think, you may install multiple Button libraries. Please check it. Or please run example code from library.
If still happened, which Arduino are you  using?

Comment: Do you mean I'd want to delete other Button libraries if I have any? I am using Arduino Uno.

Comment: I've tried deleting other Button libraries and now the code works. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can save the value of the switch read to compare it on the next loop. This way you're able to detect changes.

```
int lastValue;

void setup() {
  pinMode(7, INPUT);
  lastValue= digitalRead(7);

  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  int currentValue = digitalRead(7);
  if (lastValue != currentValue) {
    lastValue = currentValue;

    if (currentValue == HIGH) {
      Serial.println("OnsetTime");
    } else {
      Serial.println("OffsetTime");
    }
  }
}
```

Please be aware that switches bounce. If you see multiple messages at each mechanical change, insert a `delay(...)`.